# C-Linker: How divide memory with some memory sections with predefined address and fill the remaining free space?

Tags: c, memory, linker, arm, sections

I'm not really expert in C Linker and maybe what I would like to do is quite tricky.
The target platform is an ARM-CortexM4 with Gnu ARM GCC compiler.

My need is create some predefined memory sections (3,4 or more and not so large) with a predefined FLASH address (0x1000, 0x2000, ....) where I load the code and constant data of a function/functions.

Important thing is that the remaining free memory between the sections could be filled "automatically" by the linker with the remaining data without the necessity to pre-configure this activity.

Is it possible what I would like to do? In case could you give me some hints?
Thanks in advance to anyone will answer!

Answer (score 0):

simple, use a linker command file.

Note. different linkers use different command language in the linker command file.

Suggest reading: [TI linker command file primer](https://software-dl.ti.com/ccs/esd/documents/sdto_cgt_Linker-Command-File-Primer.html)

Such a file defines all the memory segment addresses, their length and gives them a name.

The each segment is defined with what its' contents will be.

One of the keywords is `fill` which can be used to fill all unused addresses with a specific value, like `0xdead`

Note that if you define all memory and give each unused (or not filled) area with a 'fill' parameter, then object file will be huge.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I knew the linker file. Maybe I wrote not so clear, the point was to create only few predefined section, with predefined address and length and the other application code filled automatically in the remaining free space. The point is if it is possible this memory configuration without pre-configure all memory sections in the linker file... for all memory section I mean the application code that has not to be inside the predefined sections/areas.